# How can I have the same initialization for all my networks?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, numpy, weight-initialization

I want to have the same weights for layer initializations in all my networks, so that when I'm comparing their first epoch loss they all start from the same value. Is there a way in keras to do this?

I have set the random seed for the numpy and tensorflow, but still I get different results in initializations.

Comment: Have a look at this https://keras.io/initializers/

Comment: @Ankit Seth yes i have set the seed for my initializer as well

Comment: hi - answered a similar question a little while back, it's a little trickier than you might think! https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37418/32697

Comment: @redhqs hi,i followed your instructions but i couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Moeinh77 what did you try, what's not working? Paste the errors if you've got them!

Comment: @redhqs no errors,the only problem is the cost function value of first epoch is different in each run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the seed *in* the initializer, e.g:

```
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform

seed = 0

model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer = RandomUniform(minval = -0.05, 
                                                       maxval =  0.05, 
                                                       seed = seed)))
```